Problem understanding what along x or y axis means in 2D vector word problem
I'm stuck on a word problem that states:

A vector $\bf B$ with a magnitude of $3.5$ meters is added to vector $\bf A$ which lies along the $x$-axis.
The sum of these two vectors is a third vector that lies along the $y\mbox{-axis}$ and has a magnitude twice the magnitude of vector $\bf A$.
What is the magnitude of the vector $\bf A$ ?.
I've no idea what is meant by "lies along the $x$/$y$ axis".
It almost sounds like a unit vector or a vector ( working with $2$D Cartesian vectors in physics class for context ) that is parallel to
the $x$ axis and another parallel to the $y$ axis.
This would be easier to solve as that would make vector $\bf B$ the hypotenuse of a right angle
triangle. Except for other exercises where this hasn't been the case.

Am I overthinking it ?. What could they mean ?.

"Lies along the x axis" means a vector of the form (v,0);  "Lies long the y axis" means a vector of the form (0,s).  Try drawing those vectors and see for yourself.

If a vector lies on the x-axis, you can imagine that the arrow lies literally on the x-axis and therefore has the form $$\left(\matrix{x\\0}\right).$$ The same applies to lying on the y-axis: $$\left(\matrix{0\\y}\right)$$ The task is easy to solve if we make sure what we know. Let $$B:=\left(\matrix{b_x\\b_y}\right).$$ From the first information of the absolute value, we know $\Vert B \Vert^2=b_x^2+b_y^2=3.5^2$. Now there should be a vector $A=\left(\matrix{a_x\\0}\right)$, which should be added with $B$ on the y - axis, that is: $$\left(\matrix{b_x\\b_y}\right) + \left(\matrix{a_x\\0}\right) =\left(\matrix{0\\b_y}\right).$$ Thus we recognize that obviously $a_x = -b_x$. Now we use the fact that the sum of $A$ and $B$ has twice the length of A according to the task, which means now:
$$\Vert \left(\matrix{0\\\ b_y}\right) \Vert = 2\cdot \Vert \left(\matrix{a_x\\0}\right) \Vert$$ or formulated differently: $$b_y^2 = 2a_x^2 = 2b_x^2$$ Let us remember that we first stated that $b_x^2+b_y^2=3.5^2 $. We now reformulate it and get $3b_x^2=3.5^2 \Leftrightarrow b_x^2 = \frac{3.5^2}{3}$. Finally, use the fact that $b_x = -a_x$, which allows you to calculate the amount of $A$ as $$\Vert A \Vert = a_x^2 = (-a_x)^2 = b_x^2 = \frac{3.5^2}{3}.$$
ALTERNATIVELY , you can work out everything geometrically using Pythagoras in the following picture.

